# android gallery app stops working after multiple crop intents in samsung galaxy note

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery, galaxy, android-camera-intent

I am firing com.android.camera.action.CROP on Galaxy Note N7000 running ICS 4.0.4, to capture and crop image. This works fine for 5-6 times of continuous runs then the default Gallery app of Android crashes. This issue is specific to only this device and is not occurring on any other devices.

I have no clue what is wrong with the Gallery app of Galaxy Note N7000, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not recommend using that `Intent` action, as it will not exist on all devices: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: @Yashesh I think you should have your own implementation for cropping images captured from Camera so that Cropping is not device dependent.

Comment: yes exactly, that's why i am checking for the availability of the activity that can respond to this intent and then crop the image ,it runs fine in initial few runs and then the gallery app stops!